# How to delete older files when append a file to a tar

Tags: linux, bash, tar

Help!

When I append some files to an existing tar file, how can i overwrite the older same name files?

```
# touch 1 2 3
# tar -cf e.tar 1 2 3
# tar -tf e.tar
1
2
3
```

The `e.tar` now has 3 file, `1 2 3`. Now I append the same file `1 2` to `e.tar`

```
# tar -rf e.tar 1 2 
# tar -tf e.tar
1
2
3
1
2
```

How can I overwrite the existing `1 2`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The `.tar` format is fundamentally append-only. However, when extracting from a tarball, only the last version of the file will be extracted.

If you want to save space, you have to create a new tarball.